# Request::query('sort_by') always returns null in view on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.3, ubuntu-16.04

I have a very weird problem getting the query parameters in view, using `Request` class ⁠⁠⁠in my dev machine⁠⁠⁠

> `⁠⁠⁠⁠Request::query('sort_by')⁠⁠⁠⁠` it returns the ⁠⁠⁠⁠actual
>   value⁠⁠⁠⁠

⁠⁠`(DevEnv: ⁠⁠⁠MacOS PHP 7.0⁠⁠⁠ Laravel Valet 2)⁠⁠`
but ⁠⁠⁠

> in production⁠⁠⁠ it always returns ⁠⁠⁠⁠`null⁠⁠⁠⁠`

`⁠⁠(ProdEnv: ⁠⁠⁠Ubuntu 16.04 PHP 7.0⁠⁠⁠ NGINX)⁠⁠`

> I have this string in the URL in browser already

[image: I have this query strings in the URL in browser already]

Comment: can you show us the request url?

Comment: Can you post some codes or method?

Comment: in view 
I have this code {{ Request::query('sort_by')⁠⁠⁠⁠ }}

Comment: You found an answer yet?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the your code by i would suggest if you can use

```
$collection=collect(⁠⁠⁠⁠Request::all());
$data=$collection->sortByDesc('yourfieldname');
OR
$data=$collection->sortBy('yourfieldname');
```

Comment: I am able to get it in controller but not in view

Comment: in View add slash before request e.g. \Request::all() OR  request()->all()  OR pass the request object from controller to view

Answer (score 1):

You are doing things wrongly. In your controller do this.

```
public function yourController()
{
    list($sortBy, $order) = explode('-', request()->get('sort_by'));
    $sortedModel = YourModel::get()->orderBy($sortBy, $order);

    // $sortedModel contain the collection with desired sorting order
}
```

With your current implementation this would be the basic approach.

But I'd like to suggest to use route as

```
/new_arrivals?sortby=price&order=desc
```

so in your controller you wouldn't need to `implode`. you can just assign params like

```
$sortBy = request()->get('sortby');
$order = request()->get('order');
```

Then you can proceed as the same. It's much cleaner.
More info on [ordering grouping limit and offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: I am not doing it wrong, I have already sorting it on controller but in view I was not getting the input to show that what was the last filter selection, it was returning null

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the `NGINX` configuration /server block was the culprit which needs some fixings,

So I changed it to this and I am getting the query parameters

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```